# unlink() function wont't delete a file

Tags: php, html

This thread was discussed many times but it didn't fix my error...
When I try to use unlink($path) function it just gives me an error, however I have permissions to delete it, the file and the path is correct, I just don't seem to find an error.

Here is my code (deleteuser.php):

```
  <?php
$path = "/thnk.php";
if (!unlink($path)) {
  echo "Error!"; 
} else {
  header("Location: index.php?deletesucces!");
}
?>
```

And HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/step/deleteuser.php" method="POST">

<button name="submit" type="submit">Delete tha user</button>

</form>

</html>
</body>
```

P.S I am very new to PHP, try to explain it as much understandable for newbies as possible! Thanks!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Double check the path

Comment: paste your error...?

Comment: Maybe you should provide us the error, by reading the error_log of your php, or by putting in place a try / catch around your unlink.

Comment: @AdrienQUINT `unlink` does not throw an exception, try / catch is useless there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have given an absolute path and I highly doubt you put the file in `/thnk.php`, rather than your document root.

**Example**

Your webserver's document root and your php files are here:

```
/var/www/public_html/
```

When you write `unlink('/thnk.php');` it will look here:

```
/thnk.php
```

But you want it to delete the file from here:

```
/var/www/public_html/thnk.php
```

That's a different "root". So you have to write

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/thnk.php');
```

Or use a relative path like

```
unlink('../thnk.php'); // which can be unsafe in some situations
```

If you don't know an error but something does not work, it is always helpful to simply enable error reporting:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: Please provide a comment why downvoting. I'm 99% sure the file as given in the path `/thnk.php` does not exist.

Comment: Why can't a file be at the root of the web app ?

Comment: `unlink()` is a C systemcall wrapper and if you put in a `/` at the beginning it will point to the filesystem root and not to the web app root.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks, I appreciate your and other people answers, thanks a lot that helped me!

Comment: Your welcome and thanks to all the server newbies for the downvotes 

Comment: Also @DanFromGermany, sorry this is completely random, but can you explain me how to delete specific line of a text with php and automatically save the file, cuz i read other people posts about this and didn't understand anything :D (stackoverflow didn't let me post another question)

Comment: @AidasPatas you would read the file (and write it at the same time) until you come to that specific line, which you skip writing, and then go on. Functions like `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fwrite()` would be used.

Answer (score 0):

first check the `file available in folder or not`

```
<?php
$filename = 'you file path';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
    unlink($filename);
    header("Location: index.php?deletesucces!");
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```